# Swift: How to do partial class implementation of a protocol (interface)?

Tags: ios, swift, oop

Coming from languages like Java/C++ we are used to partial or abstract class implementations e.g.

```
protocol ProtocolA {
   func x()
   func y()
}

// attempt to partially implement ProtocolA
class AbstractProtocolA: ProtocolA {
   func x() { /* implementation */ }

   // does not implement function y
}

class ConcreteA1: AbstractProtocolA {
   func y() { /* implementation */ }
}

class ConcreteA2: AbstractProtocolA {
   override func x() { /* implementation */ }
   func y() { /* implementation */ }
}
```

but this is not possible in Swift, in this case I would get the compilation error `Type 'AbstractProtocolA' does not conform to protocol 'ProtocolA'` ... is there another Swifty way to cover this OOD use-case?

**UPDATE:**
A way to circumvent this limitation would be to:

```
enum ProtocolAError: ErrorType {
    case NotImplementedException(methodName: String)
}

class AbstractProtocolA: ProtocolA {
   func x() { /* implementation */ }

   func y() { throw ProtocolAError.NotImplementedException(methodName: "y") }
}
```

but here we shift design/programming mistakes (i.e. instantiating the abstract AbstractProtocolA) to runtime rather than compile time.

Comment: Have you looked at extensions?

Comment: Have you looked at the `optional` keyword?

Comment: No, I haven't looked ... write an answer don't be lazy :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a default implementation of the protocol with a protocol extension:

```
protocol ProtocolA {
   func x()
   func y()
}

extension ProtocolA {
   func x() {
      // Do something (or nothing) here as a default implementation
   }
}
```

Hope it works ;)

PS: have a look to protocol oriented programming in swift, here are some links:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/109156/introducing-protocol-oriented-programming-in-swift-2
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/

Comment: I think your answer is almost there ... to cover exactly what I wanted to achieve in my OP you would take out `func y()` from the extension otherwise it doesn't answer exactly :D

Answer (score 0):

This at first looks like a bad design decision.
There are solutions like protocol extensions for default implementation, or the `optional` keyword, as posted here, but then you would have to make every method optional.
I think you should consider splitting the methods in different protocols.

Comment: I disagree, language limitations should not dictate the granularity/normalization level of your design ... you are in other words implying to end up with one-method-per-protocol design. I think extensions are the answer to my OP

Comment: @GiovanniAzua Protocols are used to ask the classes to follow a certain behaviour. It would be one thing to have a default implementation that actually does something. But having a default implementation that does _nothing_ is misusing their role, and it should tell you that that class should probably not conform to that protocol or that method should be optional. It's just as you would add that empty method in a common parent and then override it in only one child.

Comment: I never wanted a default implementation that does nothing. The OP code was simply a mock sample of the use-case I need to cover. I don't know why you assume that ...